# Overlapping date spans

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table. How I can find out overlapping spans only? In example, below memberid 3 should not be in our scope since date spans do not overlap with each other

Any help is highly appreciated

```
MemberID    fromdate    todate
1   1/1/2018    12/31/2018
1   1/1/2018    12/31/2018
2   12/1/2017   1/1/2019
2   1/2/2018    2/2/2019
3   1/1/2015    12/31/2015
3   1/1/2016    12/31/2016
3   1/1/2017    12/31/2017
4   1/1/2018    1/1/2018
4   1/1/2018    1/1/2018
5   1/1/2015    1/31/2016
5   1/1/2016    7/31/2016
5   07/01/2016  12/31/2016
```

Expected results should be data associated with Member Ids 1,2,4 and 5 Member ID 3 should not be in the results set because date spans are not overlapping.

Comment: Give a clear expected result

Comment: Expected results should be all records from above table but member ID 3 since for Member ID 3, the date spans do not overlap with each other

Comment: how about memberid 4 is it overlap?

Comment: I got a result 1,2 and 5 only not included the for because the date doesn't change anymore.

Comment: Thanks. This will help. I can handle records where from date = to date separately

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  You can get the overlapping spans by doing:

```
select m.*
from members m
where exists (select 1
              from members m2
              where m2.memberid = m.memberid and
                    m2.todate > m.fromdate and m2.fromdate < m.todate
             );
```

If you want members that don't overlap, let's use `except`:

```
select m.memberid
from members m
except
select m.*
from members m
where exists (select 1
              from members m2
              where m2.memberid = m.memberid and
                    m2.todate >= m.fromdate and m2.fromdate <= m.todate
             );
```

`Except` removes duplicates.  But if you wanted to be extra sure and redundant, you could write `select distinct` for each query.

Comment: Thanks @gordon. I updated table to add another Member ID 4. Technically, it is also overlapping and need to capture with my query as well. How can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(select memberid, convert(Varchar,fromdate,101)fromdate,convert(Varchar,todate,101)todate from @tb),
cte2 as 
(select Num,memberid,todate,fromdate,Num + 1 as num2 from 
(select  ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by memberid order by fromdate) as Num,memberid,fromdate,todate from cte) as a),
cte3 as
(select memberid,fromdate,todate, DATEDIFF(day,fromdate,todate) as date_diff from
(select ISNULL(memberid,bnum)memberid , isnull(fromdate1,fromdate2)fromdate,isnull(fromdate2,fromdate1)todate,bnum from
(select a.num,a.fromdate,a.todate,a.num2 as num1,a.memberid,case when a.Num=b.num2 then b.todate else a.fromdate end as fromdate1,
case when a.Num=b.num2 then a.fromdate else  b.todate end as fromdate2,b.num2,b.todate as todate2,b.Num as bnum from cte2 as a
full join cte2 as b
on a.num = b.num2 and a.memberid = b.memberid) as a) as a)

select distinct memberid  from cte3 where date_diff<0
```